# js trigger function when image with class .scale2by1 is added to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a function that scales all images with the class .scale2by1 on image resize:

```
export function scale2by1(images) {
    for (let image of images) {
        let height = image.clientWidth * 0.5
        image.style.height = image.style.maxHeight = height + 'px'
        image.style['object-fit'] = 'cover'
    }
}
```

I would also like to execute it when new nodes with the .scale2by1 class are added to the DOM, so they get scaled immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```
var config = { subtree: true, childList: true };
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    }
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(document.body, config);

var container = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(container);
var span = document.createElement('span')
container.appendChild(span);
```

Each item from mutationsList argument of callback function is [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord).
This record contains information about added nodes in "addedNodes" property. You can check them and do whatever you want.