# How to dynamically change select box to <ul><li> using mdb.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

We have got HTML for our project where they are using `mdb.min.js` library which convert every `<select>` box tag to `<ul><li>` format.

The problem is coming when we set piece of html code through ajax in div element. In this case, no select box is coming since its not converting to `<ul><li>` format.

Is there any way we can call dynamically any function of this library in AJAX success method which converts all select boxes ?

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".editConfiguration").click(function() {
    var cart = $(this).attr("data-cartid");
    $.ajax({

        type : 'GET',
        url : ACC.config.contextPath
                + '/configure/edit',
        data : 'cartId='+cart,
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        },
        success : function(response) {
            $("#configurationsettings").html(response);
        },
        error : function(resp) {
        }

    });
})

})
```

Comment: Reading the docs it seems like you just need to add $('.mdb-select').material_select(); to your success callback.

Comment: @iSZ.. that works actually. Thanks!!

Comment: great...I'm glad to here it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".editConfiguration").click(function() {
    var cart = $(this).attr("data-cartid");
    $.ajax({

        type : 'GET',
        url : ACC.config.contextPath
                + '/configure/edit',
        data : 'cartId='+cart,
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        },
        success : function(response) {
            $("#configurationsettings").html(response);
            $("select").material_select();
        },
        error : function(resp) {
        }

    });
})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MutationObserver to solve this problem.
Read please my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990846/js-trigger-function-when-image-with-class-scale2by1-is-added-to-dom/47991130#47991130).

This is an examle for your case:

```
var config = { subtree: true, childList: true };
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        $(mutation.addedNodes).find('.mdb-select').material_select();
    }
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(document.body, config);

var container = document.createElement('div')
container.innerHTML = `
<select class="mdb-select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Example label</label>
`;
document.body.appendChild(container);
var span = document.createElement('span')
document.body.appendChild(span);
```